# How to get request culture from IStringLocalizer implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-core

I try to create an implemantation of IStringLocalizer in asp.net core 1.1 to use a single resource file per language for my whole project (instead of one per page per language...). And I can't find how to get request language here to return values with the good culture.

I'm maybe lost in the way to implement it but documentation is very poor on the subject. Somebody can tell me how to get the good culture (user's one eq request user language) here please :

```
    public class CustomLocalizer : IStringLocalizer
{
    private readonly CultureInfo _currentCulture;
    public IEnumerable<LocalizedString> GetAllStrings(bool includeParentCultures)
    {
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(MyResources));
        foreach(DictionaryEntry value in rm.GetResourceSet(_currentCulture, false, true))
        {
            yield return new LocalizedString((string)value.Key, (string)value.Value);
        }
    }

    public CustomLocalizer(CultureInfo  culture = null)
    {
        _currentCulture = culture ?? CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture;
    }

    public IStringLocalizer WithCulture(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new CustomLocalizer(culture);

    }

    LocalizedString IStringLocalizer.this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            ResourceManager rm  = new ResourceManager(typeof(MyResources));
            return new LocalizedString(name, rm.GetString(name, _currentCulture));
        }
    }

    LocalizedString IStringLocalizer.this[string name, params object[] arguments]
    {
        get
        {
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(MyResources));
            return new LocalizedString(name, rm.GetString(name, _currentCulture));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally found where was the mistake (in my startup.cs, in Configure method I used AddMvc before setting localization options...). If it can help somebody, in other case, i'll delete this post.