# Blazor localization from database

Tags: .net, localization, blazor

I am trying to use localization from database.
I can not use .resx and really have to do localization this way.

Haven't ever before implemented localization this way, always used .resx files.

Tried with some packages (like westwind od localization.sqllocalizer) but most of them are not compatible with blazor.
Also tried to implement my own IStringLocalizer but didn't get what I should do.

Do you know where should I find how to implement this or event better if there is some package for this.

Comment: In order to get help with the question you should post some code. What have you done so far? It's perfectly fine to ask more then one question so that all together solve your problem.  For example I would start with the database. 
My data looks like this(understandable sample data). How can i use this to implement localization based on the table data in blazor. And so on...
Note: It might be relevant if blazor server or blazor wasm is the target platform. And if you want to use ef-core or ado.net etc.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I don't think how data model looks like is important for this question. To be honest still do not have database model because that is not the thing that is bothering me. What is my problem is that I haven't find any nuget package or any tutorial/example how to do this. Also haven't found any implementation of IStringLocalizer for database. The easiest part of the story is to connect to database and get that data.
Also my application currently works both in server and wasm modes.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much magic to the process. You need to get the current culture from the blazor app and a service that get's the string based on the culture.

```
public class LocalizationString
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string En { get; set; }
    public string Fr { get; set; }
}

public interface ILocalizationService
{
    string GetString(string key);
}

public class DbLocalizationService : ILocalizationService
{
    private readonly IDbConnection _dbConnection;
    private readonly CultureInfo _currentCulture;

    public DbLocalizationService(IDbConnection dbConnection, CultureInfo currentCulture)
    {
        _dbConnection = dbConnection;
        _currentCulture = currentCulture;
    }

    public string GetString(string key)
    {
        var query = $"SELECT {_currentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName} FROM LocalizationStrings WHERE Key = @Key";
        var parameters = new { Key = key };
        var result = _dbConnection.QueryFirstOrDefault<string>(query, parameters);

        return result ?? $"[{key}]";
    }
}
```

Of course this is just a sample because you provided no data.

I guess it would be a better idea to create a method that get's a range of key's since getting each key from the db seems not very performant.
It could also be an option to query the localization strings based on a task or when the app is starting. And store them in memory or in a file. But based on the information provided it's hard to determine what is the best solution for your app.

Comment: yes, but to use it on FE I would need to implement also IStringLocalizer, isn't that correct?

Comment: sure you can directly implement a custom implementation of IStringLocalizer that goes to the database in order to get the string. But as i noted before please consider the performance. In my sample instead of ILocalizationService just implement IStringLocalizer and and register it on app start to the DI container.

Comment: this might interest you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366046/how-to-get-request-culture-from-istringlocalizer-implementation. As a side note: If you would have asked how to implement IStringLocalizer to load from a db table you would have gotten a answer to that.